# Shortening long sentence based on lookup-value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

Need help: As stated in image below that I need the result in E3 to be "Washington" because based on lookup value in B6:B9 there is a matched-word **partially** (which is 'Washington') from D3's long sentence (Showroom **Washington** Furniture)

I tried vlookup but obviously it didn't work because the long sentence only match partially with the 'one-word lookup-value' in B6:B9

Appreciate if someone can tell what formula should I put in E3?

thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: Better share the Lookup formula you have tried so far!!

Comment: You may try this `=INDEX($B$6:$B$9,MATCH("*"&$B$6&"*",D$3:D$3,0))` ,, returns `Washington` in `E3` !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
=LOOKUP(1E100,SEARCH(A$2:A$5,C2),A$2:A$5)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it worked well in MS EXCEL, but not when I tried in Google Spreadsheet, do you know what formula should i put in Spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes, that's probably because the formula behaves like an arrayformula, and in excel you need to declare that through `ARRAYFORMULA`, so the whole thing will become: `=ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(1E+100,SEARCH(A$2:A$5,C2),A$2:A$5))`